# Align lightning card title and button in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

How to align the lightning card title and button on same line, in aura there is aura:set but not sure if we have anything similar in lwc:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Similar Properties" icon-name="custom:custom85">
        <lightning-button label="Neutral" title="Preview" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`slot`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots) in LWC is alternative to `aura:set`, LWC team has defined `slot` named `actions` for the action button in base component: [lightning-card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example).

You can set `slot="actions"` to the button inside [lightning-card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example), this should align the button next to title.

Code:

```html
<template>
    <div class="app slds-p-around_x-large">
        <lightning-card title="Similar Properties" icon-name="custom:custom85">
            <lightning-button label="Neutral" 
                title="Preview" class="slds-m-left_x-small" 
                slot="actions"></lightning-button>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body</p>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

Output:
[image]